# Ignoring exception in command play: discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I get this console error when I try and run the play command.

[image: console error]

The code I used is:

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url): 
    guild = ctx.message.guild 
    voice_client = guild.voice_client 
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url) 
    players[server.id] = player  
    player.start()
```

I have made sure that discord.py, ffmpeg, and youtube_dl are all up to date and I get the same error.

Comment: It looks like `voice_client` is `None`. Maybe try to print `guild`, seeing if something is up there?

Comment: @fravolt if `guild` was an issue, would've returned an error when they tried to call on `voice_client`

Comment: @Alyx I meant that if `voice_client` ends up being `none`, that indicates that `guild` does not have a `voice_client` (or it is empty). While this can be caused by many things, checking out whether `guild` contains the expected fields can help pin down the issue. Whether the error would be thrown when `voice_client` is assigned or when one attempts to access it (the line where it crashes now) depends mostly on whether `discord.py` adds the fields with value `None` or leaves them out altogether.

Comment: Oh thats a good a point!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use codeblocks to represent code and errors next time, it'll be easier to view.

You might installed the wrong version of discord.py you need another version for voice clients!
Try reinstall using this pip command:

```sh
# Linux/macOS
python3 -m pip install -U "discord.py[voice]"

# Windows
py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py[voice]
```